# How to reload tab bar items after user changes role

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift3, user-roles

When tap a button, app user can switch between two roles, user and manager.

In my `tabBarViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method,

```
if userRole == "manager" {

            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let managerHomeViewController = (mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManagerHome")) as! UINavigationController
            let managerProfileViewController = (mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManagerProfile")) as! UINavigationController
            self.viewControllers?.replaceSubrange(0...1, with: [managerHomeViewController,managerProfileViewController])
        }
```

to change first two tab bar items when loading the view.

In `anotherViewController` where user tap a button to change role,

`MainTabBarViewController().aboveFunction()`

After running this line, the tab bar items are not updated. It can **only be updated to new tab bar items by force closing the app and relaunch it**. How to reload tab bar items instantly after updating them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the solution to reload, but I eventually use **two tab bar controller** in storyboard to present two views for user and manager.

And when tapping the button to change roles

```
let homeViewController = (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManagerHomeTabBar")) as UIViewController
self.present(homeViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

to switch to the correct tab bar view.